# Exception: ObjectUnsubscribedError when working with Observables with RxJS and Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, rxjs

I am still trying to teach myself Angular2 (and I really need to find some better resources) but I have a question. I have moved my data calls to a service and I am using Reactive Subject & BehaviorSubject after instruction from a friend. My calls works, I have a mock REST service from a real back end that gives me a data object (that is an oject of mock user data), my response matches a type I have defined however in my top level app (called App.ts) I have to wait for the response. Now this is where I am doing something wrong as when I try to obtain or work with the data I get `[Exception: ObjectUnsubscribedError]` when I `console.log`.

Here's the problem, here is my top level app

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {UserContact, UserStatus} from './types/types';

// more stuff, then...

import {UserDataService} from './services/user-data/UserDataService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [...FORM_PROVIDERS, UserDataService],
    directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FooterNavigation, TopNavigation, ContactsList],
    pipes: [],
    template: require('./app.html')
})

export class App {

    constructor(public userDataService: UserDataService) {
        console.log(this.userDataService.loginInUser.last());
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // even if I try to output here I get the same problem
    }
}
```

Here is my UserDataService

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserStatus} from '../../types/types';
import {Subject, BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserDataService {

    public loginInUser: Subject<UserStatus> = new BehaviorSubject<UserStatus>(null);
    public currentUser: UserStatus;

    constructor(public http:Http) {
        this.loadUserStatus(); // Here I define the false user to use in my App
    }

    private loadUserStatus():void {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.http.get('/restservice/userstatus', {headers: headers}).subscribe((response:Response) => {
            var userStatus: UserStatus = new UserStatus(response.json());
            this.currentUser = userStatus;
            this.loginInUser.next(this.currentUser);
        }, (error:Response) => this.handleError, () => {
            this.loginInUser.complete();
        });
    }
```

The results from the `console.log(this.userDataService.loginInUser.last());` in the App.ts gives me the following:

```
_isScalar: false
completeSignal: false
destination: BehaviorSubject
dispatching: false
errorSignal: false
isUnsubscribed: false
observers: Array[0]
operator: LastOperator
source: BehaviorSubject
_hasError: false
_isScalar: false
_subscriptions: undefined
_value: UserStatus // the data does seem to be here!!!!
completeSignal: true
dispatching: false
errorSignal: false
isUnsubscribed: true
observers: undefined
value: [Exception: ObjectUnsubscribedError] // Here is the problem!!!!
```

I just want my App.ts to receive the returned data once it is ready, it obviously isn't updating... please tell me what I am doing wrong I have waisted hours on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would subscribe to the `loginInUser` observable to be notified when the current user is updated:

```
constructor(public userDataService: UserDataService) {
  this.userDataService.loginInUser.subscribe(
    (currentUser) => {
      console.log(currentUser);
    }
  });
}
```

Don't forget that an HTTP request is asynchronous so you can receive data after the constructor of your `App` component is executed.

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thanks! I didn't realise I could subscribe in he App.ts and thought I had to listen for changes using .next() or .last()

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, `next` is at the observer level to fire an event and the `last` operator allows to get the last event when you buffered events with `debounceTime` for example. To be notified, you need to subscribe on the observable... Perhaps you could have a look at this great tutorial about Rx: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: I do have another quick question regards rendering the currentUser on the interface into the DOM... should I write another question?

Comment: Yes perhaps it would be better ;-) Answering in comments isn't really convenient especially if we want to put some code snippets... But it depends on the question ;-) Let's make a try here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580852/prevent-error-rendering-to-view-when-waiting-for-async-rest-data-from-a-servic